# Не видна зависимость, добавленная gradle

Tags: java, gradle

У меня есть следующий *build.gradle* файл:

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

jar {
    baseName = 'test'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

ext{
    //versions of dependencies
    springVersion = '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    springJPAVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    javaxVersion = '1.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springJPAVersion}"
    implementation "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaxVersion}"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

И вроде проект успешно билдится:

```
21:56:37: Executing external task 'build'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
21:56:37: External task execution finished 'build'.
```

Однако когда я пытаюсь добавить импорт

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

в произвольный класс, *persistence* выделяется красным. Почему, ведь

```
 implementation "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaxVersion}"
```

должна добавить эту зависимость в проект, разве нет?

P.S. И в *C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.persistence\persistence-api\1.0.2\8...a* Gradle скачал архив *persistence-api-1.0.2.jar*, который содержит файл *javax\persistence\Entity.class*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась после нажатия "Refresh all Gradle project" в окне *Gradle projects*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]